# EasyFB not ready

Tags: angularjs, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Im using Easy Facebook for AngularJS (https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb) and sometimes it works ok, and sometimes it doesn't respond. When I do a console.log(ezfb); to see what is happening, I get this:

[image]

So I see that's not ready ($$ready: false). What could be causing this? The first time I do it, it logs in. The second time, gets like this until I clear Laravel's cache.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are facing a problem due to Larvel Cache. You can do the following things to fix your error.

1- Disable cache for your current route in `app/filter.php`.

```
Route::filter('after', function($response)
{
    // No caching for pages, you can do some checks before
    $response->header("Pragma", "no-cache");
    $response->header("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
});
```

2- Convert your cache to an array in .env

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file to CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Browser caching by

- Right-click and choose Inspect Element to open the DevTools.
- Or use one of the following keyboard shortcuts:

  F12 Control+Shift+i
  Command+Shift+i
- Click Network in the toolbar to open the network pane.
- Check the Disable cache checkbox at the top.

[image]
Also Try running these commands to clear all cache

```
php artisan cache:clear & php artisan view:clear & php artisan config:clear & php artisan route:clear & php artisan clear-compiled & php artisan config:cache  & php artisan config:clear
```

Also inside the action method of your controller use this

```
$exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

​to prevent cache